# Can you help me improve my question? 

Tags: support, asking-questions

I know I am pretty bad at posing questions, but I would like to improve. 
Can you give me some feedback on my own question, so I can improve it?  Don't just edit it; I want to know what is wrong first.

The question is [Analyze a video, look for a colored pixel or logo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8258981/look-through-a-video-and-look-for-a-pixelcolor-or-logo).

Comment: Thank you for _wanting_ to improve.

Comment: Read [this](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx) blog post and [this](http://odedcoster.com/blog/2010/08/10/getting-good-answers-on-stackoverflow-part-13-of-n/) blog series.

Comment: For this kind of questions, the chat is probably a better place where to ask them.

Comment: analyzing a video?

Comment: It is awesome that you saw the need to improve and took the initiative. Chat would be a much better venue. If everyone came here to get editorial help, we'd have thousands of questions just like this.

Answer (score 6):

A few suggestions:

- Change "look through a video" into "analyze video frames/footage",
- Mention already done investigative work,
- Tell which part exactly is or is not troubling: picking one video from a collection of videos, getting the invidual frames, searching for a pixel or logo in one frame, or writing multiple frames to a new video,
- If all of the above, say so.